# Signing Certificate for different targets

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing automation testing in iOS using XCUITtest. I have set the provisioning profile , team and all the related stuffs in xctests target but no team details is present in app side in my machine. While running the testcase in iPhone , I am getting an error as "Signing for "App" requires a development team." App side is done by other team and xctest is done by other team .
Is it mandatory to set development team from app side , while I am building on xctest ?

Answer (score 1):

It's mandatory to have signing if you test in **actual devices**. But in **Simulator** it's not mandatory..

Comment: but app is in different target and xctest is in different target .